# Can't manage to start a task when bluetooth is ready with systemd

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian, systemd

I'm trying to start a task when bluetooth is ready on a raspi (running raspbian 10 - buster) with systemd.
I've added the file /lib/systemd/system/my.service with this content

```
[Unit]
After=bluetooth.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/root/my.sh

[Install]
Wants=bluetooth.target
```

When I look at what happens on startup with the graph created by `systemd-analyse plot`, I see that my service is started way before the bluetooth.target unit is activated.
But when I check with `systemctl show my.service`, it says

```
...
After=basic.target bluetooth.target system.slice systemd-journald.socket sysinit.target
...
```

So can someone explains me why my service doesn't start after bluetooth.target?
Thanx

[edit]
I've followed advice from @ukBaz and moved my service file to /etc/systemd/system and moved the Wants stanza to the Unit section (actually I changed it to 'Requires').
So my file now contains

```
[Unit]
After=bluetooth.target
Requires=bluetooth.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/root/my.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now my service starts after bluetooth.target... but bluetooth.target gets started very early!
And `systemctl show bluetooth.target` tells me 'After=bluetooth.service' so how come it is started/reached way before bluetooth.service?

Answer (score 0):

The system’s copy of unit files are generally kept in the `/lib/systemd/system` directory. When software installs unit files on the system, this is the location where they are placed by default.

If you wish to modify the way that a unit functions or create your own, the best location to do so is within the `/etc/systemd/system` directory. Unit files found in this directory location take precedence over any of the other locations on the filesystem.

`Wants` should be in the `[Unit]` section not in the `[Install]` section.

`[Install]` section is optional and is used to define the behaviour of a unit if it is enabled or disabled. I have only every put `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in this section. The `multi-user.target` tells `systemd` (as I understand it) that it is needed for “normal operation”.